# What are the best sources of information for upcoming LEGO sets?

Tags: lego-store

LEGO sometimes offers me a "LEGO Calendar" with upcoming events, sets, sales, and coupons.  Whether or not I get this calendar is hit/miss and it only notifies me of the next month's news.  I've searched the internet for new release LEGO sets and have had problems finding a reliable single source for all sets.  Usually a site focus on one series, E.G. Ghostbusters.

What is the best place(s) to go to find this type of information?  I found the [official catalog](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/ByCatalog).  It doesn't go as far ahead as other sites.  Preferably information covering the next year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LEGO store calendars are available online about a month ahead of time. It lists the upcoming promotions, specials, new sets, store events, etc. They are the exact same ones as what you would get in the mail. You can find them in the right-hand side-bar here: http://stores.lego.com/en-us/

As far as going as far ahead as the following year, you are not going to get official information on this, as LEGO doesn't reveal their future sets more than a few months ahead the most. You will have to follow rumors and leaks, which may or may not be correct. I would suggest that you become a member of either Eurobricks or Brickset and follow the discussions on possible upcoming sets.

Also, it is a good idea to follow LEGO news at the beginning of the year, as new LEGO sets get revealed at the various toy-fairs in January/February. Pretty much all LEGO fansites will closely follow the news coming from these events. The sets displayed are usually go as far as the summer, but they will not include the large exclusives, which usually get revealed separately.